# Chrome does not consistently display text with CSS display:inline

Tags: css, inline, display

I have been using increasingly complex CSS for several years, and have usually worked out my problems, but this one has me stymied. The task was to be able to display quotations that have been edited (elisions, comments, emphases, etc.), but to allow the user to view the unedited text in either of two ways:

1. Elisions: click on the ellipsis and the elided text will appear.
2. Block: click on a edit message, and all edits will be hidden, and
   the original paragraph will appear.

In both Chrome and Safari, the first of these works, the second does not.

Here's a screen shot of the quotation before user interaction:
[image]

Note the ellipsis "[,,, The]" at the beginning of the paragraph. Here's a screenshot of the JavaScript Console:
[image]
The span for the ellipsis is highlighted in the left panel. The CSS on the right shows the display as inline. The span below that has display:none, and of course is not visible in the displayed paragraph. Here's the screenshot for that span:
[image]

Now if the user clicks on the ellipsis, here's what he'll see:
[image]
The ellipsis has been replaced by the original text. Note that other edits, comments and highlights remain. Here are the screenshots of the code for the two spans:
[image]
[image]
The display properties of the two spans are as expected.

But when the user clicks on the message at the bottom of the paragraph, here is what's displayed:
[image]
Note that the highlights and inline comments have been removed. So has the ellipsis at the beginning of the paragraph. But the original text that that ellipsis was hiding is not visible. Yet Chrome assigns it display:inline. Here is the code:
[image]
[image]
I could understand its invisibility if it were calculated as display:none; but since it's display:inline, just as it was after clicking on the ellipsis and *being displayed*, I'm perplexed.

I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: Please add a [mcve] instead of screenshots.

Comment: I am certain I can give you the answer with a simple link to your page.